# .NET - Set geolocation with selenium devtools

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to set geolocation with selenium 4 devtools in .net ?

like in java :

```java
driver.executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

I found the code below:

```vb
  Driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, driverO, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50))

           Dim devtoolsDriver = TryCast(Driver, IDevTools)
            Dim session = devtoolsDriver.CreateDevToolsSession()
            Dim emulationSettings = New Emulation.SetGeolocationOverrideCommandSettings
            emulationSettings.Latitude = -5
            emulationSettings.Longitude = 120
            emulationSettings.Accuracy = 100
            session.Emulation.SetGeolocationOverride(emulationSettings)
```

but when I run it, my application freezes